# Get multiple records with one string

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 rows in my database. They all got a different id starting at 1.

i have a string with multiple id's.

```
$str = "1,2,3,4";
```

How can i get all the records with id 1,2,3 and 4?

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = $str
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4)`

Comment: use `GROUP_CONCAT` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: Thanks @Federico it worked!

Comment: Actually, it would be "WHERE id IN ($str)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id IN ($str)
```

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id IN($str)

Comment: Refresh my comment, but shouldnt work. `$str` return a string not a collection of int.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza try `echo $str;` it output only `1,2,3,4`  and if you build query with php you get `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)`

Comment: It's always *Try, try, try*. This is what Stack is getting at now; low-quality answers.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want use  `FIND_IN_SET()`

**[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6f05/3)**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`dday` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`dday`)
VALUES
    ('1,2,3'),
    ('2,3,4'),
    ('3,4,5'),
    ('4,5,6')
;

SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, `dday`)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|  dday |
|-------|
| 1,2,3 |
| 2,3,4 |
```